# Get image URL when click on picture

Tags: javascript, image, url

I design a popup window to select imgage. this is code in Index.php

```
<input type="button" value ="Browse" onclick="browse_img()" />
<input type="text" id="img_url" name="img_url" value="selected img"/> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function browse_img(){
        window.open("img_browse.php","windows2");
    }
</script>
```

This is code in img_browse.php

```
<img id="img_id_1" src="url/puc1.jpg" onclick="select_img()"/>    
<img id="img_id_2" src="url/puc2.jpg" onclick="select_img()"/>
<input type="text" id="img_url" name="img_url" value="selected img"/>
<scrip>
   function select_img(){
        var file_url=$(this).src; 
        alert(file_url);
        document.getElementById("img_id_2").value=file_url;
    }
</scrip>
```

The aler say "undefined". help me!
And how do i pass img_url from windows2 (img_browse.php) to index.php

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  If so, `$(this).attr('src')` should work.  But this doesn't make much sense - you know which image is being clicked - you shouldn't need any logic to determine it.

Comment: Pass this object for the function:
onclick="select_img(this)"
function select_img(obj) { var file_url = $(obj).attr["src"] .......

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<img id="img_id_1" src="url/puc1.jpg" onclick="select_img(this.src)"/>
```

And the javascript:

```
function select_img(src) {
  alert(src);
  document.getElementById("img_id_2").value=src;
}
```

Comment: Thank Zack Tanner so much!

Answer (score 0):

> html code

```
<img (click)="addImageToReport($event)"
     [src]="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20220208/ourmid/pngtree-3d-icon-of-rocket-for-startup-business-and-bitcoins-advertise-png-image_4381459.png"/>
```

> js code

```
addImageToReport(selectedImage: any) {
    let value = selectedImage.target.src;
    console.log(value);
  }
```